# Python with Excel, counting the cells

Tags: python, excel, pandas, openpyxl

I do have an excel sheet that has 30000 rows in it. I want to categorize the first 5 rows with for example #1. the second 5th rows with #2 and so on until reaching 30000 rows. how can I do that with excel sheet.

[image]

```
lst1 = []
classifier = 0
while classifierOne <= 30000:
    if classifier <= 5:
        lst1.append(1)
    if classifier > 5 and classifier<=10:
        lst1.append(2)
      ::
      ::
      ::
      ::
      ::
      ::
      ::
      ::
    classifierOne +=1
# do this until I reach 30000 which is not an efficient way to do.

print(lst1, classifierOne)

df = DataFrame({'':lst1})
df.to_excel('list.xlsx', sheet_name='sheet1', index=False)
```

I have tried many ways But I couldn't find and efficient way to do this. Your help is appreciated.

Comment: `if classifier > 5 and classifier>=10:` ???? what?

Comment: why don't you append `classifier//5 + 1` to your list?

Comment: What state is the Excel data currently in? Did you read it into a DataFrame already?

Comment: Sorry, I just updated it. I don't want to append the classifier I just want to append the number that corresponding to range that I want as you can see in the sheet I provide as an example.

Comment: Wait, I don't understand the question. You want to replicate Python behaviour in Excel, or you want to use Python to write this back to Excel? I can't see you having any will to live if you've already implemented the `while classifierOne <= 30000:` method... but you have "how can I do that with excel sheet."

Comment: @roganjosh. the question is, Can I use another way other that using if statements all the way up to 30000. I just want to categorize the rows till reaching the last row. first 5 rows has number ONE, second 5 rows has number TWO, third 5 rows has number THREE and so on.

Comment: @Ali in that case, Jean-Francois has provided a good answer to your issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can generate such a list easily with a flat double list comprehension, repeating each number five times:

```
n = 5
lst1 = [i for i in range(1,30000//n+1) for _ in range(n)]
```

that issues 30000/5 numbers (6000), each one is repeated 5 times (so 30000 rows).

result:

```
[1,
 1,
 1,
 1,
 1,
 2,
 2,
 2,
 2,
 2,
 3,
 3,
 3,
 3,
 3,
 4,
 4,
 4,
 4,
 4,
 5,
 5,
 5,
 5,
 5,
 etc...
```

Comment: Thank you Jean-Francois. Can you please explain `//n) for _ in range(n)`